The Fourth Daughter
Proud as punch, the parents Dr and Sergeant Pepper beamed from side to side. The birth of their fourth daughter, a younger sister to Alice, Buffy and Victoria was the cause for this elation. Sergeant Pepper looked out the hospital window to the Christmas scene outside. His daydream was cut short by an interruption from his good friend Don Rivers.  "Well Pepper, you sure produce these girls with metronomic regularity - never seen anything like it - every fifteen months - have you a name?"    Pepper smiled "Surely it's obvious Don - there is a pattern".  "Not like my Daisy, Lily and Rose" countered River, to which Pepper replied: "It's one of Shelley, Angel, Carroll or Kate - I am sure you'll get it!"
What was the fourth daughter going to be called?

It's...

 Shelley.  Working backwards from the Christmas scene,  the kids are born in Spring, Summer, Fall, Winter respectively and we have Alice Springs(s), Buffy Summer(s), Victoria Fall(s),  Shelley Winter(s).  N.B.  Since there is a well known Katie Winters, I suggest changing that option (unless the similarity of the names was intended as part of the puzzle).



! Well done - Shelley was the one I was looking for


I figured, the other isn't spelled right, though it looked right without my glasses.  Sigh.
